# how to get users list depending on their roles in Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I use MVC5 EntityFramework 6

I have a clinic app with list of users, every user has account role (Doctor, Nurse, Lab)

how to create DropDownList of(Doctors) or (Nurse) or (Lab)

all users and roles are predefined by default (Individual User Accounts)

users are (ApplicationUser)
Roles are (IdentityRole)
I update tables names as this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5izES2OQ2k)

all users are in the same table `Users` all Roles are in `Roles` and I combined between them in `UserRoles` Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solved using the following code

in  Controller

```C#
string DoctorRoleID = roleManager.FindByName("Doctor").Id;
ViewBag.DoctorID = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == DoctorRoleID)).ToList(), "Id", "Email");
```

In View

```C#
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DoctorID, "DOCTOR", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("DoctorID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndUserID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data for your drop down is id & value pairs, then you just need to select a different query – but returning the same type – depending on the data wanted.

Eg.

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, string>> GetNames(NameType nt) {

  if (nt == NameType.Nurse) {
    return from n in db.Nurses
           select new KeyValuePair {
             Key = n.Id,
             Value = n.Name
           };
  } else if (nt == NameType.Doctor) {
    return from d in db.Doctors
           select new KeyValuePair {
             Key = d.Id,
             Value = d.ProfessionalDisplayName
           };
  }

  [...]

}
```

You can of course use a custom type (including anonymous: all anonymous types in the same assembly with the same members (name & value) in the same order are the same type); and encode the type of person in the id (eg. to save keeping track separately).

Comment: I updated my question, all users are in the same table `Users` all Roles are in `Roles` and I combined between them in `UserRoles` Table

Comment: @AbdallahSabri Are you asking how to do a simple join between users, users-in-role, and roles tables?

Comment: yes, I need to create a dropdownlist of users depending on their roles

Comment: So just perform the necessary DB query: but that will depend on the database structure you have. But you'll need to join users to usersInRoles to roles and filter on role.